docker login "connection refused" but only when the engine is running
I have a private registry in Kubernetes which I have connected to using
kubectl port-forward docker-registry-6bc94649d-529hq 443:5000
I can successfully log in and interact with it via curl requests and in my browser, but for some reason Docker (Docker Desktop - Windows) I can see in the port-forward that there was not even a request for it to handle. I have added a rule to allow connections for the docker exe files, and I also tried turning off the firewall completely and still nothing. Any help would be massively appreciated, thanks.
Without the engine running:
C:\Users\josep>curl -k https://localhost:443/v2/_catalog -u admin:pass
{"repositories":[]}

C:\Users\josep>docker login 127.0.0.1:443 -u admin -p pass
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Login Succeeded

C:\Users\josep>docker image list
error during connect: this error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running: Head "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/_ping": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.

Now with the engine running:
C:\Users\josep>docker login 127.0.0.1:443 -u admin -p pass
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get "http://127.0.0.1:443/v2/": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused

C:\Users\josep>docker image list
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID   CREATED   SIZE


Does curl work without the -k option? And does it work if you use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost (which might be resolving to ipv6).

@BMitch it does not
curl: (60) schannel: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.

But I also had this set up on http before with the address in insecure-registries and it still didnt work and never managed to get the request to kubernetes anyway

I found it was an issue with Docker Desktop running the engine in a virtual machine (here) and so I changed my port-forward command to:
kubectl port-forward docker-registry-7dc967c478-qkx5k --address=192.168.0.228 443:5000
This way, the registry could be accessed by the engine in the virtual machine.
